# Reference the dll file from the qt project

Tags: qt, dll, reference, for-loop

How do i reference the dll file from the qt project. can someone give me the sample .pro file?

Thx.

Comment: Do you want to reference it or do you just want to compile something on Windows and be able to run it on a different Windows machine?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the .a (if you are using MinGW) that comes with your DLL and add a line like this one your .pro file:

```
LIBS += "PathToLib/libcryptopp.a"
```

Please refer to Qt documentation, it's pretty complete: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs

You could also load dynamically the DLL using QLibrary

Comment: To make it more complete: on Windows you should reference .lib (it's the Windows equivalent of .a).

Also you can right-click in the .pro and select 'Add Library...' This will present a wizard and will generate the code for you. It allows to browse/specify external, internal and system libraries and will also generate the platform related code as well (you can specify the platform of the library (Windows, Mac, Linux, Symbian) and the type of the library (dynamic/static)).